# How do I get all the files on a GitHub folder using GDscript?

Tags: json, github, godot4

I want to get the name of every file in the folder OnlineLevels/VerifiedLevels/ in my GitHub repository. I used the HTTPRequest node and got the data from the GitHub API.

Here's my code:

```
func _ready():
    $HTTPRequest.request_completed.connect(_on_request_completed)
    $HTTPRequest.request("https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/main?recursive=1")

func _on_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var json = JSON.parse_string(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    print(json)
```

This is the result:

```
{ "sha": "b5d857af5cbe4450855fbf2ef0e96c875f3c08b7", "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/b5d857af5cbe4450855fbf2ef0e96c875f3c08b7", "tree": [{ "path": "OnlineLevels", "mode": "040000", "type": "tree", "sha": "7804f8fafc98a105759074811601e6ebcf84e667", "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/7804f8fafc98a105759074811601e6ebcf84e667" }, { "path": "OnlineLevels/VerifiedLevels", "mode": "040000", "type": "tree", "sha": "73722f67c4161c2100c447008c8d9ef109a82c68", "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/73722f67c4161c2100c447008c8d9ef109a82c68" }, { "path": "OnlineLevels/VerifiedLevels/CBLevel_Ice mode test.json", "mode": "100644", "type": "blob", "sha": "efd553f8f995434029f17ec48e8211c4985cc1df", "size": 2061, "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/blobs/efd553f8f995434029f17ec48e8211c4985cc1df" }], "truncated": false }
```

I'm not very good with JSON so this might be a simple question, but it would be great if someone could help me.

Edit: I found out that [this page](https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/73722f67c4161c2100c447008c8d9ef109a82c68) shows results only for the folder I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess it actually was a simple question.

Here is the code I used:

```
func _ready():
    $HTTPRequest.request_completed.connect(_on_request_completed)
    $HTTPRequest.request("https://api.github.com/repos/SuperGames-D/ColorBlocks/git/trees/main?recursive=1")

func _on_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    $Loading.visible = false
    var json = JSON.parse_string(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    
    var json_tree = json["tree"]
    for i in json_tree:
        var path = i["path"]
        path = path.replace("CBLevel_", "")
        path = path.replace(".json", "")
        if "OnlineLevels/VerifiedLevels/" in path:
            path = path.replace("CBLevel_", "")
            path = path.replace(".json", "")
            path = path.replace("OnlineLevels/VerifiedLevels/", "")
            addLevel(path)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).